# Typhoon-example app - Cannot get it to run

Tags: ios-simulator, typhoon

I am trying to learn how to use Typhoon, the Objective-C IOC. I have cloned the example app Typhoon-example (pocket forecast) from GitHub. It builds but when I run it it will not start the IOS simulator

I am using Xcode 5.1.1.

Can anyone help? Has anyone experienced the same problem?

I was wondering whether the problem was that the project seems to be targeting IOS 6.0. I down loaded the IOS Simulator for 6.1, but it still did not work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry My mistake I had the wrong target selected. Its working now.

Once again sorry for wasting your time